# How to get access token with roles for specific client?

Tags: keycloak, openid-connect, access-token

I have setup similar to this in keycloak:

- Client:

  - frontend (public, getting token from this client)
  - backend1 (confidential)
  - backend2 (confidential)
- Client scope:

  - roles_all (to include users' roles for each client in the token)
  - roles_backend1 (to include only roles for backend1)
  - roles_backend2 (to include only roles for backend2)

What I need is to only get roles for specific clients instead of all clients in the token. I made it work by adding a Client scope (roles_backendX) for each client and sending scopes in the token request but I am wondering if there is a simpler way. For example request the roles_all scope but with a specified client eg. scope=roles_all:backend1 or scope=roles_all.backend1

Something like that would save me a lot of manual setup.

EDIT: (ideallly)

- Client:

  - frontend (public, getting token from this client)
  - backend1 (confidential)
  - backend2 (confidential)
- Client scope:

  - roles_all (optional)

and login with something like:
auth.server.com/realms/SomeRealm/protocol/openid-connect/auth?response_type=code&clientid=frontend&**scope=roles_all:backend1 roles_all:backend2**...

Answer (score 2):

1.) Clients should have `Full Scope Allowed` disabled

2.) Then you can play with mappers/scope config (e.g. `User Realm role` mapper type) or with client scope (abstraction for group of mappers - you can configure them as assigned default scopes, so you won't need to specify them explictily in the token request)

Comment: I think I have that, I have default scopes without the roles and in optional scopes i add a scope for each client - this is what I want to avoid. If possible I dont want to create a scope for each client and then add that scope to optional. Id like to just add the scope with all client roles and "query" specific clients i want in the access token from frontend client via the request parameter.

eg: auth.server.com/realms/SomeRealm/protocol/openid-connect/auth?...clientid=frontend&scope=roles_all:backend1 roles_all:backend2...

Comment: @nubi I am not sure if I quite understand you, but did you try to create the scopes under the realm Client Scopes tab, and then switch to Default Client Scopes and add then? I think this will add the optionals scopes to all clients in one go.